# Referencing different rows in UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Now that I have my UIPicker split into multiple rows, how do I reference those individual rows when setting their values?

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPickerView` `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol has a method `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` - the component is the "wheel" you are concerned with, indexed from 0 at the left. The row is the list of values that can appear in a component. You must set the UIPickerView `delegate` and `datasource` members to an object or objects that implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols. If you have it split into multiple components (vertical columns or wheels) already then you have probably already got a `UIPickerViewDataSource` set up.